# Formatting Cout Output in C++

Tags: c++

This is the expected output:

```
COUNT | WORD 
------+------
   1  | .3
   1  | .3.4
   1  | 3
   2  | 12.34
   1  | test1.12.34
   3  | this
```

This is my proper code:

```
std::cout << "COUNT | WORD" << '\n';
std::cout << "------+------" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  std::setw(3) << ".3" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  std::setw(3) << ".3.4" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  std::setw(3) << "3" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "2" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  std::setw(3) << "12.34" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  std::setw(3) << "test1.12.34" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "3" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  std::setw(3) << "this" << '\n';
```

Unfortunately, my ouput's messy the WORD

```
COUNT | WORD
------+------
   1  | .3
   1  |.3.4
   1  |  3
   2  |12.34
   1  |test1.12.34
   2  |this
```

Could anyone suggest me a solution for that. Thanks

Comment: add a `\t` between the `|` and the numbers in the WORD columns

Comment: Your three reserved spaces are getting filled, so it's continuing on to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having

```
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  std::setw(3) << ".3" << '\n';
```

For each line, add a space after the '|' character:

```
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << "| " <<  std::setw(3) << ".3" << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not this ::

```
std::cout << "COUNT | WORD" << '\n';
std::cout << "------+------" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  ' ' << ".3" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  ' ' << ".3.4" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  ' ' << "3" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "2" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  ' ' << "12.34" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "1" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  ' ' << "test1.12.34" << '\n';
std::cout << std::setw(4) << "3" << std::setw(3) << '|' <<  ' ' << "this" << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this will set the left hand side filler character.

```
cout.fill('-');
cout.width(40);
cout<< "LINE1" <<endl;

cout.fill('-');
cout.width(40);
cout<< 3 <<endl;

cout.fill('-');
cout.width(40);
cout<< 3.4 <<endl;

cout.fill('-');
cout.width(40);
cout<< "TEST " << 12.34 <<endl;
```